# Make long names shorter in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, alias

Instead of writing a code like

```
FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().gameOver()
```

I would like to type just

```
gm.gameOver()
```

Is there a way to do that in Unity?

Maybe using some kind of alias, or some kind of namespace or something else. I am after making my code clean, so using GameManger gm = FindObjectOfType() in every file that uses a the GameManager is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5):

In general I have to discourage this question. This is very questionable and I would actually not recommend this kind of shortening aliases for types and especially not for a complete method call ... bad enough when it is done with variables and fields by a lot of people.

Always use proper variable and field names thus that by reading the code you already know what you are dealing with!

---

how about storing it in a variable (or class field) at the beginning or whenever needed (but as early as possible)

```c#
// You could also reference it already in the Inspector
// and skip the FindObjectOfType call entirely
[SerializeField] private _GameManager gm; 

private void Awake() 
{ 
    if(!gm) gm = FindObjectOfType<_GameManager>(); 
}
```

and then later use

```c#
gm.gameOver();
```

where needed.

In general you should do this only once because `FindObjectOfType` is a very performance intense call.

This has to be done of course for each class wanting to use the `_GameManager` instance ...

However this would mostly be the preferred way to go.

---

Alternatively you could also (ab)use a **Singleton pattern** ... it is *controversial* and a lot of people hate it kind of ... but actually in the end `FindObjectOfType` on the design side does kind of the same thing and is even worse in performance ...

```c#
public class _GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Backing field where the instance reference will actually be stored
    private static _GameManager instance;

    // A public read-only property for either returning the existing reference
    // finding it in the scene
    // or creating one if not existing at all
    public static _GameManager Instance
    {
        get 
        {
            // if the reference exists already simply return it
            if(instance) return instance;

            // otherwise find it in the scene
            instance = FindObjectOfType<_GameManager>();

            // if found return it now
            if(instance) return instance;

            // otherwise a lazy creation of the object if not existing in scene
            instance = new GameObject("_GameManager").AddComponent<_GameManager>();

            return instance;
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

so you can at least reduce it to

```c#
_GameManager.Instance.gameOver();
```

---

the only **alias** you can create now would be using a `using` statement at the top of the file like e.g.

```c#
using gm = _GameManager;
```

then you can use

```c#
gm.Instance.gameOver();
```

it probably won't get much shorter then this.

But as said this is very questionable and doesn't bring any real benefit, it only makes your code worse to read/maintain! What if later in time you also have a `GridManager` and a `GroupMaster`? Then calling something `gm` is only confusing ;)

---

Btw you shouldn't start types with a `_` .. rather call it e.g. `MyGameManager` or use a different [`namespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace) if you wanted to avoid name conflicts with an existing type

Comment: Why is the singleton pattern controversial? I use it a lot and it is a great way of keeping track of things, should I not use it?

Comment: @barteezy for Unity I also often use it but people will direct you to posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons) ;)

Comment: so instead of writing one line FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().gameOver();, I now have to write 
GameManager gm;
...
void Awake() { 
        if(!gm) { gm = FindObjectOfType<GameManager>(); } 
}
...
gm.gameOver()